# Efficient method for counting number of data points inside sphere of fixed radius centered on each data point

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy

I have a database with many data-points each with an x,y,z coordinate. I want to count the number of points that are within a certain distance to neighboring points. Some points will have a pair that is within a radius R, others will not. I simply want to count the number of pairs within some distance. I could easily write an algorithm to do this but it would not be efficient enough (for I would iterate over every single data point).

This seems like something that must already exist in astropy, scipy, etc. but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. Is there anything out there that accomplishes this?

Comment: What proof do you have that "it would not be efficient enough"?

Comment: Finding an existing implementation is off-topic, but what you want is a spatial search data structure like a *k*-*d* tree, octree, or simple cell bins.

Comment: @martineau True. I haven't actually implemented it, I am just assuming that it would take a very long time to use the distance formula over 2 million times but maybe this would actually be feasible... It just seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Jake: 2M isn't that much (depending on exactly what you're doing) and there are trivial ways of speeding up the distance calculation—such as using the value squared. It can be difficult sometime, but premature optimization is something to generally be avoided. A famous computer scientist (supposedly) once claimed it's the root of all evil.

Comment: The astronomy and astropy tags don't really seem relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Davis Herring in the comments, an efficient option is a k-d tree.

The k-d tree is an algorithm that avoids the brute-force approach and allows for efficient distance computations* (see bottom of answer for background).

There are several Python implementations of this, one of which is through `SciPy`:

[SciPy k-d tree in Cython](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) (faster since it uses C/Cython)

[SciPy k-d tree in pure Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

You can use this by first constructing a k-d tree for your xyz data:

```
import numpy as np  #for later code
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

kdtree = cKDTree(xyzData)
```

Then, you must query the k-d tree with a point `point` to compute the distance between `point` and its nearest neighbor. The output of this query is the distance `NN_dist` between `point` and its nearest neighbor and the index `NN_idx` of that neighbor. To compute this for all of your points, we need a for loop, but given the k-d tree algorithm, this is much faster than a brute-force computation:

```
NN_dists = np.zeros(numPoints)  #pre-allocate an array to store distances
for i in range(numPoints):
    point = xyzData[i]

    NN_dist, NN_idx = kdtree.query(point,k=[1])

    #Note: 'k' specifies the kth neighbor distance to compute, 
    #so set k=2 if you end up finding the point as its own "neighbor":
    if NN_dist == 0:
        NN_dist, NN_idx = targetTree.query(curCoord,k=[2])
    
    NN_dists[i] = NN_dist
```

(see [k-d tree query](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query) for more details).

Then, to find the distances that are below some threshold, you could use the built-in utility of NumPy arrays when using comparison operators (like `<`):

```
distanceThres = 10
goodIdx = NN_dists < distanceThres
goodPoints = xyzData[goodIdx]
```

This will give you the indices `goodIdx` and points `goodPoints` that are within your specified distance threshold `distanceThres` (though you may have to change this code depending on the shape/format of your xyz coordinate data).

---

*A light background on k-d trees (glossing over fine details -- see references for more): the k-d tree method partitions a dataset in such a way that avoids computing the distance between every single point (i.e., the brute force method). It does this by dividing the dataset into binary space partitions to construct a k-d tree. These partitions are such that a distance computation (e.g., a nearest-neighbor search) can ignore datapoints that are in distant partitions. Additionally, this same k-d tree is reused for each point.

There are a lot of resources online about k-d trees in general. I found these references most helpful when I was learning about this algorithm: [Stanford k-d trees](http://stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106l/cs106l.1162/handouts/assignment-3-kdtree.pdf) or [Princeton k-d trees](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr13/cos226/lectures/99GeometricSearch.pdf).

Let me know if you have questions -- I had this exact problem myself during an astronomy project, so I may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with it but [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) may be what you're looking for.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312205/find-the-k-nearest-neighbours-of-a-point-in-3d-space-with-python-numpy) may be helpful as well. It gives an example of how to solve the problem as I understand it.