# Need a function that returns an estimate equal to the mean of the closest k points to the number p?

Tags: python, numpy, knn

Define a function that takes a 1-d NumPy array, a parameter k, and a number p. The function returns an estimate equal to the mean of the closest k points to the number p?

def k_neighbor(input_data, k, p):
    """Returns the k-neighbor estimate for p using data input_data.

```
Keyword arguments:
input_data -- NumPy array of all the data
k -- Number of k
p -- input values
```

Here is the function call

data = np.array([1,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,15,19,24,25,29,40])
print(k_neighbor(input_data=data, k=3, p=5))

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126771/nearest-neighbour-search-kdtree ?

Comment: @joris : i did but mine is single dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

Copying from [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array) and adjusting a bit gives what you want:

```
import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value,n_neighbors=1):
    distances=np.abs(array - value)
    print(distances)

    nearest_neighbors=[]
    for i in range(0,n_neighbors):
        idx=distances.argmin()
        nearest_neighbors.append(array[idx])
        distances[idx]=np.amax(distances)

    return nearest_neighbors

data=np.array([1,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,15,19,24,25,29,40])
value=24
print(find_nearest(data, value,n_neighbors=3))
```

returns

> [24, 25, 19]

Comment: in the above code if I take value=25 then it gives 25 as nearest neighbor   import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value,n_neighbors=3):
    distances=np.abs(array - value)

    nearest_neighbors=[]
    for i in range(0,n_neighbors):
        idx=distances.argmin()
        nearest_neighbors.append(array[idx])
        distances[idx]=distances.argmax()  

    return nearest_neighbors

data=np.array([1,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,15,19,24,25,29,40])
value=25
print(find_nearest(data, value,n_neighbors=3))

Comment: import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value,n_neighbors=3):
    distances=np.abs(array - value)

    nearest_neighbors=[]
    for i in range(0,n_neighbors):
        idx=distances.argmin()
        nearest_neighbors.append(array[idx])
        distances[idx]=distances.argmax()  

    return nearest_neighbors

data=np.array([1,3,4,5,7,8,11,12,13,15,19,24,25,29,40])
value=25
print(find_nearest(data, value,n_neighbors=3))  value is repeated in this case

Comment: i've changed it so it also returns the three closest numbers when the search value is already there. But i'm sure you could have done this yourselve.