# Optimizing nested iterators in python

Tags: python, numpy, cycle

Say, that fig1 and fig2 are numpy 2d arrays of shape (n1, 2) and (n2, 2), which basically are lists of coordinates. What I'm tying to do is to count a mean Hausdorff distance between two figures presented as sets of dots. Here is what I've came up with:

```
@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)   
def dist(fig1, fig2):
    n1 = fig1.shape[0]
    n2 = fig2.shape[0]
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    min1 = np.full(n1, np.inf)
    min2 = np.full(n2, np.inf)

    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(n2):
            dist_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt((fig1[i, 0] - fig2[j, 0])**2 + (fig1[i, 1] - fig2[j, 1])**2)
            min1[i] = np.minimum(min1[i], dist_matrix[i, j])
            min2[j] = np.minimum(min2[j], dist_matrix[i, j])

    d1 = np.mean(min1)
    d2 = np.mean(min2)
    h_dist = np.maximum(d1, d2)
    return h_dist
```

That works perfectly, but I'd like to **avoid** these nested **`for`**'s, hopefully via vectorization. Can somebody suggest any possible variants?

If needed I can give some generators of figures.

Comment: I'm sure somebody has figured out a better solution than a `O(n1 * n2)` time complexity (quadratic!!!)... Have you tried searching on google for a better algorithm to calculate the "Hausdorff distance"?

Comment: I found a website that seems to have a better algorithm (scroll down to `3.3 Algorithm`): http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html

Comment: the speed trick in numpy is to perform the loops in compiled numpy methods.  But that requires learning numpy basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Methods

1. Using [KDTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126771/nearest-neighbour-search-kdtree)
2. [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) with posted approach

**Code**

```
# Method 1--KDTree
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

def dist_kdtree(fig1, fig2):
    ' Distance using KDTree '

    # KDTree data structures for fig1 & fig2
    # which provides for nearest neighbor queries
    fig1_tree = KDTree(fig1)
    fig2_tree = KDTree(fig2)

    # Nearest neighbors of each point of fig1 in fig2
    nearest_dist1, nearest_ind1 = fig2_tree.query(fig1, k=1)

    # Nearest neighbors of each point of fig2 in fig1
    nearest_dist2, nearest_ind2 = fig1_tree.query(fig2, k=1)

    # Mean of distancess
    d1 = np.mean(nearest_dist1)
    d2 = np.mean(nearest_dist2)
    return np.maximum(d1, d2)

# Method 2--Numba on posted approach
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def dist_numba(fig1, fig2):
    n1 = fig1.shape[0]
    n2 = fig2.shape[0]
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    min1 = np.full(n1, np.inf)
    min2 = np.full(n2, np.inf)

    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(n2):
            dist_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt((fig1[i, 0] - fig2[j, 0])**2 + (fig1[i, 1] - fig2[j, 1])**2)
            min1[i] = np.minimum(min1[i], dist_matrix[i, j])
            min2[j] = np.minimum(min2[j], dist_matrix[i, j])

    d1 = np.mean(min1)
    d2 = np.mean(min2)
    h_dist = np.maximum(d1, d2)
    return h_dist

# Baseline--Original version
import numpy as np

def dist(fig1, fig2):
    n1 = fig1.shape[0]
    n2 = fig2.shape[0]
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    min1 = np.full(n1, np.inf)
    min2 = np.full(n2, np.inf)

    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(n2):
            dist_matrix[i, j] = np.sqrt((fig1[i, 0] - fig2[j, 0])**2 + (fig1[i, 1] - fig2[j, 1])**2)
            min1[i] = np.minimum(min1[i], dist_matrix[i, j])
            min2[j] = np.minimum(min2[j], dist_matrix[i, j])

    d1 = np.mean(min1)
    d2 = np.mean(min2)
    h_dist = np.maximum(d1, d2)
    return h_dist
```

**Performance Test**

```
# Create two random 2D arrays
np.random.seed(0)
fig1 = np.random.random((100, 2))
fig2 = np.random.random((500, 2))

# Time original
%timeit dist(fig1, fig2)
Out: 815 ms ± 49.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Time KDTree
%timeit dist_kdtree(fig1, fig2)
Out: 1.66 ms ± 88.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Time Numba
%timeit dist_numba(fig1, fig2)
Out: 770 µs ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Summary*

- KDTree provided 490 speed up over original (1.6 ms vs. 815 ms)
- Numba provided a 1K speed up over original (770 us vs. 815 ms)

Comment: Yup, I already use it. But i wanna as much more speed as possible, so that's why I'm curious if it can be improved.
Thnx, btw, for a great advice)

Comment: @DimaHuro--thought of a second method (i.e. KDTree) so added it.  It also provides a significant speed up.